# What does inspecting a weapon do?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, you can press the 'F' key (default) to "Inspect" your weapon. This causes your player to move the held weapon around in the player's hands a bit.

What does "Inspecting" a weapon in-game do? Furthermore, will inspecting a weapon slow me down if I move and inspect at the same time? If I inspect a weapon, can other players hear me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspecting a weapon has no effect on gameplay.  What happens is, some weapons feature StatTrak capabilities, which add a "kill" counter to all of your weapons. Sometimes, [like for knives, the kill counter is etched into the knife, where for guns, it's counted through a display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgoRg.png).

Inspecting your weapon will allow you to view the kills you have (if you have a StatTrak version) and look at your brand spanking new gun/shank/thing.  See below:

[image]

Notice the kill counter in the side of that AUG. It reads "000006".

Note, you can simply click or switch weapons to get out of inspect mode.  Going into inspect mode doesn't force you to wait through the whole animation.

Comment: Thanks, but does inspecting a weapon slow me down or make sound that other players can use to locate me?

Comment: No, it doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't think of it like that :P